# Delete multiple rows in sql

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables like this:

```
Table L   
 A | B  
 C | D

Table K     
 A | B   
 C | D  
 E | F
etc etc
```

I whish to delete in `table K` all the lines that exist in `Table L`.

However when I do delete it will only eliminate the first line. I would like that if more lines where inserted into `Table L` that coincide with lines in `Table K` the delete would work as well, this is, not having to do a "manual" delete

Thanks in advance

Comment: mysql or sqlite?  remove the wrong tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delete with an alias and an existential quantifier to accomplish that:

```
delete k
from K as k
where exists (
    select * from L as l
    where l.col1=k.col1 and l.col2=k.col2
)
```

Comment: @SOaddict Right. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, my query was mostly right except I had an = after the where clause. that helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  FROM K 
WHERE ( Col1,Col2 ) 
  NOT IN 
( 
  SELECT k1.Col1, k1.Col2
    FROM K k1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN L l1
      ON k1.Col1 = l1.Col1
     AND k1.Col2 = l1.Col2
    WHERE l1.Col1 IS NULL OR l1.Col2 IS NULL
);
```